# Get htaccess URL params in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, url, get, parameters

Is there any way in Javascript to get the parameters ume modified URL with htaccess?
As an example: www.website.com/argument/1/argument/2
Where "/argument/2" = &product_id=2
There is some way to pick up these parameters in JavaScript?

Comment: You would need to access them via the rewritten URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export these properties by simply printing the map as JSON. I'm going to show this in PHP.

```
<script>
var GET = <?= json_encode($_GET); ?>;
</script>
```

Then you can access the values as `GET['product_id']`.

Comment: PHP i know how to get that. I Want this in Javascript only.

Comment: The page in which the JS will be included is created server-side, I suppose. Just put the snippet I posted at the top of the page (somewhere in `<head>`) and you can access the parameters the way you need in JS (the last sentence in my answer is about JS, not PHP). You cannot do it any other way as the routing process that (via mod_rewrite) is done server-side.