# Why does my HTML page see the original path and not the Apache rewritten URL and query string?

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I have a very simple .htaccess file that maps to another file name and adds a query string:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^foo$ index.html?id=42 [QSA]
```

However in my page what I see is the original path:

```
console.log("location = " + window.location); // foo
console.log("search = " + window.location.search); // empty
```

Note that my index.html page does load/execute and print the values... so the rewrite is happening.  It's just that the page isn't getting the rewritten URL.  Should it be?  I see many examples of people rewriting paths as query strings using this technique... How are they getting the resulting query/search string?
thanks.

EDIT: To clarify I was trying to do this with plain JS and Apache rewrites (no other server involved).

Comment: Looks like you want to retrieve it using javascript, and I doubt it win run in your case because javascript is loaded when the final page appears, in this case /foo, so I guess you can not know the rewrite rule or get its parameters in javascript in this way due the redirection in .htaccess.  Using PHP you can get them via $_GET or $_REQUEST.

Comment: It seems this is the way it is and I'll just have to parse the (resulting) pathname.  Seems weird to me that the page executes thinking its at the original URL... which means that it has to have knowledge of the mappings to function...

Comment: If you are creating the output html via PHP then maybe you still have an opportunity to fix it, see this easy trick in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194010/get-htaccess-url-params-in-javascript.  Apart from that, due possible XSS security issues, I am not sure you have to rely in javascript for that really.

Comment: Thanks.  I clarified in the question that I was trying to do this with plain JS and Apache.  I guess I just have to write the page logic to accept either format.